# Pulling different records from multiple tables as one transaction history list

Tags: mysql, history, multiple-tables

I am working on an employee management/reward system and need to be able to show a single "transaction history" page that shows in chronological order the different events that the employee has experienced in one list. (Sort of like how in facebook you can goto your history/action section and see a chronological list of all the stuff that you have done and affects you, even though they are unrelated to eachother and just have you as a common user)

I have different tables for the different events, each table has an employee_id key and an "occured" timestamp, some table examples:

```
bonuses
customers
raise
complaints
feedback
```

So whenever an event occurs (ie a new customer is assigned to the employee, or the employee gets a complaint or raise) a new row is added to the appropriate table with the employee ID it affects and a timestamp of when it occured.

I need a single query to pull all records (upto 50 for example) that include the employee and return a history view of that employee. The field names are different in each table (ie the bonus includes an amount with a note, the customer includes customer info etc).

I need the output to be a summary view using column names such as:

```
event_type = (new customer, bonus, feedback etc)
date
title (a brief worded title of the type of event, specified in sql based on the table its referencing)
description  (verbiage about the action, such as if its event_type bonus display the bonus amount here, if its a complain show the first 50 characters of the complaint message or the ID of the user that filed the complaint from the complaints table. All done in SQL using if statements and building the value of this field output based on which table it comes from. Such as if its from the customers table IF current_table=customers description='A customer was assigned to you by'.customers.assigner_id).
```

Ideally,

Is there any way to do this?

Another option I have considered, is I could do 5-6 different queries pulling the records each from their own table, then use a mysql command to "mesh/interleave" the results from all the queries into one list by chronological order. That would be acceptable too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `UNION` query to merge all the information together and use the `ORDER BY` clause to order the actions chronologically.  Each query must have the same number of fields.  Your `ORDER BY` clause should be last.

The examples below assume you have a field called customer_name in the customers table and bonus_amount in the bonuses table.

It would look something like this:

```
SELECT   'New Customer' as event_type, date, 
         'New customer was assigned' as title, 
         CONCAT('New Customer: ', customer_name, ' was assigned') as description
FROM     customers
WHERE    employee_id = 1

UNION

SELECT   'Bonus' as event_type, date, 
         'Received a bonue' as title, 
         CONCAT('Received a bonus of $', FORMAT(bonus_amount, 2), '.') as description
FROM     bonuses
WHERE    employee_id = 1

UNION

...

ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Could you elaborate how you might write one of the expressions? (Pick any sample of conditions). Its been ages since Ive used expressions in that manner and am drawing a blank onto the syntax (searching now but getting lots of generic WHERE expressions, or if you have a link to this specific usage kb article that would work too)

Comment: I gave a couple examples.